# How to preserve snippets stored in Chrome dev tools upon clearing browsing data

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I clear browsing data (Ctrl + Shift + Del), all my snippets (Sources tab) stored inside Chrome Dev tools gets deleted. I have to recreate them.

I don't want this to happen, as long as I don't clear them myself.
How to preserve them indefinitely?

Thanks
bt

Comment: This can also happen if your profile gets corrupted which can happen if you use something like CCleaner or sometimes  seemingly for no reason at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you deleting your browsing data you can uncheck **Cookies and other site and plugin data** checkbox:

[image]

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose of deleting your browsing data (or at least greatly reduces the usefulness of deleting browsing data)